# Bootstrap files are not loading at run time

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, spring-mvc

[File Structure in eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LA0fP.jpg)
Css files are not loading at run time  so that i lost my design which i did. Below is my code for login page but the thing is am getting links for css files which are not loading if i click that link that file will open in the eclipse IDE

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <title>Login Page</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- MetisMenu CSS -->
    <link href="../bower_components/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="../dist/css/sb-admin-2.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="../bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">   
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                <div class="login-panel panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h3 class="panel-title">Please Sign In</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <form role="form" action="login" method="get">
                            <fieldset>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail" name="userName" type="text" autofocus>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" type="password" value="">
                                </div>
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    <label>
                                        <input name="remember" type="checkbox" value="Remember Me">Remember Me
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                                <!-- Change this to a button or input when using this as a form -->
                                <!-- <a href="AdminHome.jsp" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block">Login</a> -->
                               <input type="submit" value="login" />
                           <br>

                           <div class="dropdown">
                            <button class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Registration Yourself
                                 <span class="caret"></span></button>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li><a href="StudentByAdmin.jsp">Student</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="ParentsByAdmin.jsp">Parent</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="TeacherByAdmin.jsp">Teacher</a></li>
                                   </ul>
                                <p><a href="#">Forgot your password ?</a></p>
                            </div>
                         </fieldset>

                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Metis Menu Plugin JavaScript -->
    <script src="../bower_components/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
    <script src="../dist/js/sb-admin-2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try ~ instead of .. in     <link href="~/bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

Comment: No, that will not give link itself in eclipse ide

Comment: thats what i have conclude reference links are not working as expected

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because it is unable to find out that location in root directory

Comment: if i remove spring configuration web.xml its working

Answer (score 0):

For the Welcome page no need to add   ../

```
<link href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

keep like this

```
<link href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: after spring configuration again not picking frorm server

Answer (score 0):

```
     <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <!-- MetisMenu CSS -->
     <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/metisMenu/2.5.2/metisMenu.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/1.0.8/css/sb-admin-2.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
     <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css"    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Metis Menu Plugin JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/metisMenu/2.5.2/metisMenu.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/1.0.8/js/sb-admin-2.js"></script>
```

Comment: use cdn's if not working go to browser console check it'll show the required version